# What is the intersection of the keys of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter, reduce

I'm trying to write a one liner function using map, filter, reduce that takes is a list of dictionaries (Ld) and returns a collection of the keys that are contained in all the dictionaries (the intersection of the keys).

The function below attempts to do this. The map portion returns a collection of True/False if the key is in a particular dictionary. The reduce returns True if all of such elements are true. Lastly, the filter portion filters out all the keys that don't satisfy such conditions.

```
def intersection_of_keys(Ld):
    return filter(lambda key: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda dic: key in dic, Ld)), all_keys(Ld))

#For example:  
d1 = {1:12, 3:4, 2:5}  
d2 = {1:6, 3:8, 0:9}  
d3 = {3:0, 1:11, 2:3}  
Ld = [d1, d2, d3]  
print(intersection_of_keys(Ld))
```

The code should print a collection containing 1 and 3. But the variable ***key*** inside the **map** portion is undefined. Any ideas why ***key*** is not passed into the lambda function definition for the map? And any ideas of how to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It seems to work just fine (once I provide a suitable `all_keys` definition and `list`-ify the resulting `filter` object):  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BS8QwEIXv@RUPvDSSw7ZRcQN79bT/QGSpnRRD06SkKWyR/e11sroHQec08/Fm5r1pzR8x6K1PcUS/hC7H6Ge4cYopI1laOruR7dF6fxrsOldHkkaAK9m8pIBqQB8TCC7gSNd@KD1JIcqiC9mm2XbZxXCK/d9HeudZVfl2fKcWLDE/v2/orMDsfL8qjO10o@Q6U9TXf65TbEBK9csru7h7YU/23I6TtwYQVOOAz9rUjYI2DwqNebwIar7pU4HPCjuzZ6gL1GanwPq6SPVFcMwDXolH4hOk38SUOGbl3Zyr//JKuW1f "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Can you provide a traceback or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using a one liner with `set` and `&`:

```
from functools import reduce

d1 = {1:12, 3:4, 2:5}  
d2 = {1:6, 3:8, 0:9}  
d3 = {3:0, 1:11, 2:3}  
Ld = [d1, d2, d3]

reduce(lambda x, y: x&y.keys(), Ld)
>>>{1, 3}
```

If you can't use `set` and `&` and must stick with `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: [i for i in x if i in y], Ld)
>>>[1, 3]
```

Finally if you can't even use list comprehensions and need to use `filter`:

```
list(reduce(lambda x, y: filter(lambda a: a in y, x) , Ld))
>>>[1, 3]
```

Comment: The keys views are already set-like, so it's a little wasteful to convert them to sets explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

`filter`, `reduce`, `map`, and `lambda`... oh my! This is Python, remember, so don't make this harder than it needs to be. Just using a good ol' for-loop:

```
>>> keys, *morekeys = [d.keys() for d in Ld]
>>> for k in morekeys: 
...     keys &= k 
...
>>> keys
{1, 3}
```

If you insist on using reduce, it's like this:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import and_
>>> reduce(and_, [d.keys() for d in Ld])
{1, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error. If I run the code you provided (replacing `all_keys(Ld)` with `(k for d in Ld for k in d)`, and wrapping the call in `list` so it runs out the `filter`), I get:

```
[1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BS8QwEIXv@RUPvDSSw7ZRcQN79bT/QGSpnRRD06SkKWyR/e11sroHQec08/Fm5r1pzR8x6K1PcUS/hC7H6Ge4cYopI1laOruR7dF6fxrsOldHkkaAK9m8pIBqQB8TCC7gSNd@KD1JIcqiC9mm2XbZxXCK/d9HeudZVfl2fKcWLDE/v2/orMDsfL8qjO10o@Q6U9TXf65TbEBK9csru7h7YU/23I6TtwYQVOOAz9rUjYI2DwqNebwIar7pU4HPCjuzZ6gL1GanwPq6SPVFcMwDXolH4hOk38SUOGbl3Zyr//JKuW1f)

which, while redundant, accurately describes the overlapping keys in the order they're seen.

That said, if you don't *need* to write it with `.keys()`/`map`/`filter`/`reduce`, there is a *much* better way to do this, as long as the exact ordering of the keys, and redundancy of output seen above isn't needed:

```
def intersection_of_keys(Ld):
    return set(Ld[0]).intersection(*Ld[1:])
```

That's it; [`set.intersection` takes varargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), so you can pass it many things to intersect with as a single operation.